# fs.promises.writeFile resolves before it finishes writing the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am probably missing something obvious with this, but I have spent several days looking for solutions to this issue and have not found any.

I have a function that takes in an object, turns it into a string, and then uses the node File System to save it. It is supposed to wait for the file to finish writing before it returns, however, for whatever reason it does not.

Instead, the function begins writing the file and calls the `.then ()` and continues before the file has been written. The file does finish writing, but it only happens after the promise has already been resolved, and thus, after the function has already continued.

I'm using node.js and it's native `fs.promises` api which is what a lot of similar questions suggest (although many of them are from when fs.promises was still experimental)

The code:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
const path = require (`path`);

var server = `test`;
const settings = {
  "name": "srvr.name",
  "serverId": "srvr.id",
  "ownerId": "srvr.ownerId",
  "prefix": "!",
  "roles":
  {
    "bot":
    {
      "id": "srvr.me.roles.highest.id",
      "name": "srvr.me.roles.highest.name"
    }
  }
};

saveSettings (server, settings);
```

Function:

```
async function saveSettings (server, settings) {

  const newSettings = await JSON.stringify (settings, null, `\t`);

  await fsPromises.writeFile (path.join (__dirname, `${server}.json`), newSettings)
  .then (console.log (`File Saved`));

  await console.log (fs.readFileSync (path.join (__dirname, `${server}.json`)));

  return console.log (`Settings Saved`);
}
```

Expected Result:

```
File Saved
{
  "name": "srvr.name",
  "serverId": "srvr.id",
  "ownerId": "srvr.ownerId",
  "prefix": "!",
  "roles":
  {
    "bot":
    {
      "id": "srvr.me.roles.highest.id",
      "name": "srvr.me.roles.highest.name"
    }
  }
}
Settings Saved
```

Actual Result:

```
File Saved
<Buffer 7b 0a 09 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 20 22 73 72 76 72 2e 6e 61 6d 65 22 2c 0a 09 22 73 65 72 76 65 72 49 64 22 3a 20 22 73 72 76 72 2e 69 64 22 2c 0a 09 22 ... 150 more bytes>
Settings Saved
```

As you can see, the file is still being written when the function attempts to read it.

From my understanding, fs.promises.writeFile returns a promise that will be resolved when the file has finished writing, but it doesn't appear to be doing so.

I started using fs.writeFile, however discovered that it did not return a promise and therefore await would not work with it.
I have also tried fs.writeFileSync, just in case that might have worked, but as expected, it did not.

I do not know if the object is too large, and so the file takes too long to write, but as far as I can tell, that shouldn't be an issue, as the promise should not resolve until the file has been written, regardless of how long it takes.

I know I am probably missing something very obvious here, whether I'm missing the way `writeFile` works, or am using the wrong function altogether, but I do not know what.

In case it is useful, this function is for use in a Discord bot using Discord.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: `As you can see, the file is still being written when the function attempts to read it.` See where?

Comment: Add the encoding to readFileSync `readFileSync(..., 'utf8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was noted in the comments by user Phix, but for good measure, the issue isn't that the file was still being written, but that by default readFile returns a *buffer*, not a string. The solution is to pass the encoding option to readFile/readFileSync, which probably should be `utf-8`. For good measure, you should also include that encoding when you write the file.